Why my deviceId changes when saving it to the Keychain using KeychainSwift?
This is how I generate deviceId:
class Device {
    private let device: UIDevice
    private let keychain: Keychainable
    var deviceIdentifier: String {
        guard let identifier = keychain.decode(forKey: StorageKey.DeviceIdentifier) else {
            let uuid = device.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
            keychain.encode(value: uuid, forKey: StorageKey.DeviceIdentifier)
            return uuid
        }
        return identifier
    }
}

and this is how my keychain is defined:
import KeychainSwift

protocol Keychainable: AnyObject {
    func encode(value: String, forKey key: String)
    func decode(forKey key: String) -> String?
    func delete(forKey key: String)
}

class Keychain: Keychainable {
    private let keychain: KeychainSwift
    init(keychain: KeychainSwift) {
        self.keychain = keychain
    }

    func encode(value: String, forKey key: String) {
        keychain.set(value, forKey: key)
    }

    func decode(forKey key: String) -> String? {
        keychain.get(key) //
    }

    func delete(forKey key: String) {
        keychain.delete(key)
    }
}

But for some reason through the time the app is used deviceIdentifier changes. Why? It definitely should not. Where is the issue?
My first idea is that in the line marked with  there is an issue while fetching string for key, and then it generates a new one. Is it possible?

How are you testing this? If you're testing local Xcode builds or builds installed via ad-hoc certificates, then this is expected. The docs for identifierForVendor explicitly state that "The value can also change when installing test builds using Xcode or when installing an app on a device using ad-hoc distribution. ".

Have you read and understood the exact code I post in the question?;) It is totally not about identifierForVendor. I know when it changes...

You could add a print statement or set a breakpoint to confirm that the value wasn't found in keychain. Are you testing on a real device or simulator?  IdentifierForVendor can change during development and it is possible that this change is also associated with a new keychain (because the underlying app identitifier changes). This seems to be particularly common on simulator devices.
